How to control the latency of packets in a distributed application deployed using Docker / Docker container?
I am trying to use Docker for a network simulation, to see the impact of network latency. My requirements are as follows.
I want to setup my distributed application in 4-20 number of containers, each deployed in different VMs
Then I need an overlay network, that will allow each docker contained application to communicate with each other
Then in the real time, I need to play with the latency of packets between each container
So far, the following is what I could come up with

Deploy the application in multiple containers mounted in multiple VMs

Expose the ports to outside Docker, so that applications can communicate using TCP

Use Linux NetEm (a tool that allows to control latency / jitter / packet loss) in each VM and control the traffic using tc


The above solution works, however, it is not neat. It uses Docker, but also uses VM level network manipulation
So, my question is: in Docker / Docker Swarm, is there a built in way where I can (1) deploy an application in n VMs, (2) let each container talk with each other, (3) manipulate the latency and packet drop of each messages sent from each container
Thank you
